# Chrome and O3d not updating

Tags: macos, google-chrome, updates

**Update**: *Chrome and o3d are now at latest versions, not sure if they are updating properly though, and can't really check until next release.*

Whenever chrome or o3d try to update themselves on my system (MBP, Mac OS 10.5.7) it fails, I assume this is a permissions error as I set up my account to be a sudoer, but not an administrator.

I have tried to update manually (Chrome > About > Update Now) it downloads and mounts the disk image of the update, but then unmounts it and displays the message "Self update failed."

Any ideas on how to figure out what's going wrong?

**Edit**:

I tried the update both on a real admin account and an entirely unprivileged account, both with the same results.

permissions (by ls -le) are

```
drwxrwxr-x@  3 acobb  admin   102 Jun 12 21:00 Google Chrome.app
```

console spits out a lot:

```
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669] 2009-07-16 21:58:50.561 GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent[92673/0xa076c720] [lvl=2] -[KSAgentApp setupLoggerOutput] Agent settings: <KSAgentSettings:0x128bc0 bundleID=com.google.Keystone.Agent lastCheck=2009-07-16 21:52:59 -0600 checkInterval=18000.000000 uiDisplayInterval=604800.000000 sleepInterval=1800.000000 jitterInterval=900 maxRunInterval=0.000000 isConsoleUser=1 ticketStorePath=/Users/acobb/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/TicketStore/Keystone.ticketstore runMode=4 daemonBootstrapName=com.google.Keystone.Daemon logEverything=0 logBufferSize=2048 alwaysPromptForUpdates=0 productIDToUpdate=com.google.Chrome lastRun=2009-07-16 21:52:53 -0600 lastUIDisplayed=2009-06-26 18:47:58 -0600 lastCheck=2009-07-16 21:52:59 -0600 alwaysShowStatusItem=0 userGUID={D92DFBBA-D345-43A9-8AE1-8A9F6C6363CE} updateCheckTag=(null) printResults=YES userInitiated=YES handlingCrash=NO> 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669] 2009-07-16 21:58:51.903 GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent[92673/0xb00a1000] [lvl=2] -[KSUpdateEngine updateProductWithProductID:] No ticket for product with Product ID com.google.Keystone 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669] 2009-07-16 21:58:51.904 GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent[92673/0xb00a1000] [lvl=2] -[KSUpdateEngine processingStarted:] processor=<KSActionProcessor:0x150700 isProcessing=1 actions=4 current=(null)> 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669] 2009-07-16 21:58:51.904 GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent[92673/0xb00a1000] [lvl=2] -[KSUpdateEngine processor:startingAction:] processor=<KSActionProcessor:0x150700 isProcessing=1 actions=3 current=KSCheckAction>, action=<KSCheckAction: 0x156f70> 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669] 2009-07-16 21:58:51.905 GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent[92673/0xb00a1000] [lvl=2] -[KSCheckAction performAction] filteredTickets = <CFArray 0x1580d0 [0xa03911a0]>{type = immutable, count = 1, values = ( 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669]  0 : <KSTicket:0x155240 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669]  productID=com.google.Chrome 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669]  version=3.0.189.0 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669]  xc=<KSPathExistenceChecker:0x13d830 path=/Applications/Google Chrome.app> 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669]  url=https://tools.google.com/service/update2 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669]  creationDate=2009-06-08 16:40:49 -0600 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669] > 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669] )} 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669] 2009-07-16 21:58:52.505 GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent[92673/0xb00a1000] [lvl=2] -[KSOmahaServer updateInfosForResponse:data:] Attributes from XMLNode <updatecheck DisplayVersion="3.0.192.0" codebase="http://dl.google.com/chrome/mac/GoogleChrome-3.0.192.0.dmg" hash="lQ28L1yRtI56Z4iH/2sd81m+LCg=" needsadmin="false" size="12140537" status="ok"></updatecheck> = { 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669]     DisplayVersion = "3.0.192.0"; 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669]     codebase = "http://dl.google.com/chrome/mac/GoogleChrome-3.0.192.0.dmg"; 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669]     hash = "lQ28L1yRtI56Z4iH/2sd81m+LCg="; 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669]     needsadmin = false; 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669]     size = 12140537; 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669]     status = ok; 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669] } 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669] 2009-07-16 21:58:52.507 GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent[92673/0xb00a1000] [lvl=2] -[KSUpdateEngine processor:finishedAction:successfully:] processor=<KSActionProcessor:0x150700 isProcessing=1 actions=3 current=KSCheckAction>, action=<KSCheckAction: 0x156f70>, wasOK=1 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669] 2009-07-16 21:58:52.507 GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent[92673/0xb00a1000] [lvl=2] -[KSUpdateEngine processor:startingAction:] processor=<KSActionProcessor:0x150700 isProcessing=1 actions=2 current=KSPrefetchAction>, action=<KSPrefetchAction: 0x157500> 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669] 2009-07-16 21:58:52.507 GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent[92673/0xb00a1000] [lvl=2] -[KSPrefetchAction performAction] prefetches=( 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669]         { 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669]         DisplayVersion = "3.0.192.0"; 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669]         kServerCodeHash = "lQ28L1yRtI56Z4iH/2sd81m+LCg="; 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669]         kServerCodeSize = 12140537; 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669]         kServerCodeSize = 12140537; 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669]         kServerCodebaseURL = http://dl.google.com/chrome/mac/GoogleChrome-3.0.192.0.dmg; 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669]         kServerDisplayVersion = "3.0.192.0"; 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669]         kServerProductID = "com.google.Chrome"; 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669]         needsadmin = false; 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669]         status = ok; 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669]     } 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669] ) 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669] 2009-07-16 21:58:52.638 GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent[92673/0xb00a1000] [lvl=2] -[KSDownloadAction performAction] Short circuiting download of http://dl.google.com/chrome/mac/GoogleChrome-3.0.192.0.dmg, path=/Users/acobb/Library/Caches/com.google.UpdateEngine.Framework.501/Downloads/com.google.Chrome.dmg, size=12140537, hash=lQ28L1yRtI56Z4iH/2sd81m+LCg= 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669] 2009-07-16 21:58:52.638 GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent[92673/0xb00a1000] [lvl=2] -[KSUpdateEngine processor:finishedAction:successfully:] processor=<KSActionProcessor:0x150700 isProcessing=1 actions=2 current=KSPrefetchAction>, action=<KSPrefetchAction: 0x157500>, wasOK=1 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669] 2009-07-16 21:58:52.638 GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent[92673/0xb00a1000] [lvl=2] -[KSUpdateEngine processor:startingAction:] processor=<KSActionProcessor:0x150700 isProcessing=1 actions=1 current=KSSilentUpdateAction>, action=<KSSilentUpdateAction: 0x157600> 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669] 2009-07-16 21:58:52.639 GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent[92673/0xb00a1000] [lvl=2] -[KSMultiUpdateAction performAction] filteredUpdates=( 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669]         { 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669]         DisplayVersion = "3.0.192.0"; 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669]         kServerCodeHash = "lQ28L1yRtI56Z4iH/2sd81m+LCg="; 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669]         kServerCodeSize = 12140537; 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669]         kServerCodebaseURL = http://dl.google.com/chrome/mac/GoogleChrome-3.0.192.0.dmg; 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669]         kServerDisplayVersion = "3.0.192.0"; 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669]         kServerProductID = "com.google.Chrome"; 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669]         kTicket = <KSTicket:0x1c60a0 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669]  productID=com.google.Chrome 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669]  version=3.0.189.0 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669]  xc=<KSPathExistenceChecker:0x1bdfc0 path=/Applications/Google Chrome.app> 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669]  url=https://tools.google.com/service/update2 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669]  creationDate=2009-06-08 16:40:49 -0600 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669] >; 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669]         needsadmin = false; 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669]         status = ok; 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669]     } 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669] ) 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669] 2009-07-16 21:58:52.739 GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent[92673/0xb00a1000] [lvl=2] -[KSDownloadAction performAction] Short circuiting download of http://dl.google.com/chrome/mac/GoogleChrome-3.0.192.0.dmg, path=/Users/acobb/Library/Caches/com.google.UpdateEngine.Framework.501/Downloads/com.google.Chrome.dmg, size=12140537, hash=lQ28L1yRtI56Z4iH/2sd81m+LCg= 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669] 2009-07-16 21:58:55.039 GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent[92673/0xb00a1000] [lvl=3] -[KSInstallAction performAction] Return code 4 from an install script. output1: (null), output2: , output3: (null) 
7/16/09 9:58:55 PM [0x0-0x1316315].com.google.Chrome[90669] 2009-07-16 21:58:55.043 GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent[92673/0xb00a1000] [lvl=3] -[KSAgentApp(KeystoneDelegate) engine:finished:wasSuccess:wantsReboot:] Finished with com.google.Chrome : success 0, should reboot 0
```

Answer (score 3):

What version of Chrome do you have now?

In the console it doesn't explicitly say why it aborts the download of http://dl.google.com/chrome/mac/GoogleChrome-3.0.192.0.dmg other than an install script fails. You could try manually downloading the update as a workaround but it sounds like the Google Update Engine is broken on your computer. You can try a re-install of o3d, or remove the Google Update Engine to force it to re-install.

To do this you run:
`sudo /Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/Resources/GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent.app/Contents/Resources/install.py --uninstall` from the command line.

Comment: hmm, odd... I ran it and checked Chrome again and it was up to date, not sure if it was the uninstall or something else. now just to wait and see if the next update works (will accept answer then if it does), thanks :)

Comment: Ooh, the `install.py` is probably the install script. You should look through the source and see if you can find out what the return value `4` means.

Answer (score 2):

First thing to do is check Console, in `/Applications/Utilities`. Chrome may have logged a message about the problem. Also, you could try setting your account as admin and updating to see if that works.

Edit: you should also check the permissions on the `/Applications` folder, and on Chrome itself, using Get Info in Finder (⌘I).

Edit2: well, the only thing I can get out of that is the "`Return code 4 from an install script`". I'm not sure which install script that would be, though you might try poking through some application packages and the internets.